# Link between the servlet and the JSP doesn't work for the second time

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc

Am developing a simple CRUD application using JDBC, JSP, and Servlets in the MVC fashion. 
After running the code on Container, In the main page on clicking the update link, It gets directed to a JSP where we can make changes and traverse back to the main page.

Issue 1 - The above action happens only for the very first time after running the code on Container if I try to update data in the same field or to another field the Update button doesn't work for the second time.

Issue - 2 Once I click on the update link in the student table I will get redirected to the update page after clicking on save "Button on this page" I should get redirected back to the main page with Student Table, But as soon as this action is done the updated student is getting deleted.

How to fix this?

I have attached this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vBkqbv3cQUdnA3aFp3ZEpJSFk/view where people can download this app and run it on your system just in case.

Regards
-Shhiv.

StudentControlllerServlet - Servlet

```
package WebJDBC;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet("/StudentControlllerServlet")
public class StudentControlllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ Resource (name ="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        //Create a instance of the student DB util
        //pass the connection pool datasource
        try{
        StudentDButil dbobject = new StudentDButil(datasource);
        }
        catch(Exception exe)
        {
            throw new ServletException(exe);
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String theCommand = request.getParameter("command");
            if(theCommand==null)
            {
                theCommand="LIST";
            }

            switch (theCommand)
            {
            case "LIST":
            listStudents(request,response);
            break;

            case "ADD":
                addStudents(request,response);
                break;

            case "LOAD":
                loadStudents(request,response);

            case "UPDATE":
                UpdateStudent(request,response);

            default:
                listStudents(request,response);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

    }


private void UpdateStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("studentID"));
    String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    Student updatedStudentdetails = new Student(id,fname,lname,email);

    StudentDButil.updateStudents(updatedStudentdetails);

    listStudents(request,response);

    }

//Used to create a pre-populated form for student upgrade
    private void loadStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        //Read the student id from  the form data
    String studentID = request.getParameter("studentID");


        //get the student from the DB (dbutil)
        Student students = StudentDButil.getStudents(studentID);


        //place that student in the request attribute
        request.setAttribute("studentId", students);



        //Sending these stuff to the JSP page
        RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("update.jsp");
        disp.forward(request, response);
    }




    //Used to get the vaule from the form
    private void addStudents (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{


        //read the student info from the form
            String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");


            //Create a new student object
            Student student = new Student(fname,lname,email);


            //add the student to the DB
            StudentDButil.addStudent(student);


            //send them back to the main list
            listStudents(request,response);
    }


    //Copying the student objects from the List in getStudents() to the students List ---- Forwarding the request to the View
    private void listStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        // Get students from the DB util;

        List<Student> students = StudentDButil.getStudents();


        //Add students to the request object;
        request.setAttribute("List_Students", students );

        //Send it too the JSP

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/list_Student.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }




}
```

Student.java  - Helper Class

```
package WebJDBC;

public class Student {

    private int studentID;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    public Student(int id, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.studentID = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Student [studentID=" + studentID + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email="
                + email + "]";
    }




}
```

StudentDButil - Model Servlet

```
package WebJDBC;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class StudentDButil {

    private static DataSource datasource;

    public StudentDButil(DataSource thedatasource)
    {
        datasource = thedatasource;
    }

    public static List<Student> getStudents() throws Exception
    {
        List<Student> stud = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Connection myCon = null;
        Statement myStat = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;



        try{
            // Get a connection
            myCon = datasource.getConnection();

            // SQL statement

            myStat = myCon.createStatement();

            // Executing the query
            myRs = myStat.executeQuery("select * from student order by last_name");

            //Process ResultSet
            while(myRs.next())
            {
                // retrieve data from the result set
                int id = myRs.getInt("id");
                String firstname = myRs.getString("first_name");
                String lastname = myRs.getString("last_name");
                String email = myRs.getString("email");

                //create new student object
                Student newStudent = new Student(id, firstname, lastname, email);

                //add it to the list of students
                stud.add(newStudent);
            }

            return stud;
        }

        finally{
            close(myCon,myStat, myRs);

        }

    }

    private static void close(Connection myCon, Statement myStat, ResultSet myRs) {
        try{
            if(myRs != null)
            {
                myRs.close();
            }
            if(myStat != null)
            {
                myStat.close();
            }
            if(myCon != null)
            {
                myRs.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(Student student) throws SQLException  {
        //Create sql for insert 
        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myPStat = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;


            try
            {
                //get Connection
                myCon = datasource.getConnection();

                //Creating SQL insert
                String sql = "insert into student"
                            + "(first_name, last_name, email)"
                            + "values(?,?,?) ";

                myPStat = myCon.prepareStatement(sql);

                //Get values from the paramas
                myPStat.setString(1, student.getFirstname());
                myPStat.setString(2, student.getLastname());
                myPStat.setString(3, student.getEmail());

                //Execute SQL
                myPStat.execute();
            }
            finally
            {
                close(myCon, myPStat, myRs);
            }
    }

    public static Student getStudents(String studentID) throws Exception {
        Student theStudent =null;
        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myPStat = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        int studid;

        //Convert Student ID to int
        studid = Integer.parseInt(studentID);
        //Get connection to the database
        try
        {
        myCon = datasource.getConnection();
        String Sql = "Select* from student where id=?";
        //Create prepared statement 
        myPStat = myCon.prepareStatement(Sql);
        //Get params
        myPStat.setInt(1, studid);
        //Execute
        myRs = myPStat.executeQuery();

        if(myRs.next())
        {
            String First_Name = myRs.getString("first_name");
            String Last_Name = myRs.getString("last_name");
            String Email = myRs.getString("email");

            theStudent = new Student(studid, First_Name, Last_Name, Email);
        }

        else
        {
            throw new Exception ("Couldn't find student ID:" + studid);
        }
        return theStudent;
        }
        finally
        {
        close(myCon, myPStat, myRs);
        }
    }

    public static void updateStudents(Student updatedStudentdetails)throws Exception {
        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myPStat = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {
            myCon = datasource.getConnection();

            String Sql = "Update student "
                        + "set first_name=? , last_name=?, email=? "
                        + "where id=?";

            myPStat = myCon.prepareStatement(Sql);

            myPStat.setString(1, updatedStudentdetails.getFirstname());
            myPStat.setString(2, updatedStudentdetails.getLastname());
            myPStat.setString(3, updatedStudentdetails.getEmail());
            myPStat.setInt(4, updatedStudentdetails.getStudentID());

            myPStat.execute();
        } 
        finally {
            close(myCon, myPStat, myRs);
        }

    }

    public static void DeleteStudent(String studentID) throws Exception {

        int studeid = Integer.parseInt(studentID);

        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myPStat = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {
            myCon = datasource.getConnection();

            String SQL = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id = ?";

            myPStat = myCon.prepareStatement(SQL);

            myPStat.setInt(1, studeid);

            myPStat.execute();
        } 
        finally
        {
            close(myCon, myPStat, myRs);
        }

    }   


    }
```

list_Student.jsp - View Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <%@ page import = "WebJDBC.*" %>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Data Table</title>



<link type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>


<body>

<div id ="wrapper">

<div id ="header">
 <h1> <cite>  Foobar University </cite> </h1>


</div>

<div id="Container">

<div id ="content">

<br>
<input type="button" value="Add-Student" 
 onclick="window.location.href='add-student-form.jsp';return false;"
class="add-student-button"
/>

<table>
 <tr>
    <th> First name </th>
    <th> Last name </th>
    <th> Email </th>
    <th> Actions </th>
 </tr>


    <c:forEach var ="ts" items="${List_Students}">

    <c:url var="templink" value="StudentControlllerServlet">
        <c:param name="command" value="LOAD" />
        <c:param name="studentID" value="${ts.studentID}"/>
    </c:url>

    <c:url var="templink2" value="StudentControlllerServlet">
        <c:param name="command" value="DELETE" />
        <c:param name="studentID" value="${ts.studentID}"/>
    </c:url>

    <tr>
        <td> ${ts.firstname} </td>
        <td> ${ts.lastname} </td>
        <td> ${ts.email} </td>
        <td> <a href="${templink}"> UPDATE </a> | <a href="${templink2}" 
        onclick="if(!(confirm(''Are you sure you want to Delete this student'))) return false"> DELETE </a> </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

</div>

</div>
<div align="right">

  <h5> <i> <a href ="index.html"> Back to the starter page </a></i> </h5>


</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

add-student-form.jsp JSP code to add a student

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Add Student</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/add-student-style.css">    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>FooBar University</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h3 id="header"> Add Student </h3>

        <form action="StudentControlllerServlet" method="GET">

            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="ADD" />

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Last name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>


        <div align="right">
        <p>
            <a href="StudentControlllerServlet" >Back to List </a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

update.jsp

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Update Student</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/add-student-style.css">    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>FooBar University</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h3 id="header"> Update Student </h3>

        <form action="StudentControlllerServlet" method="GET">

            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="UPDATE" />
            <input type="hidden" name="studentID" value="${studentId.studentID}" />
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" value="${studentId.firstname}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Last name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastName" value="${studentId.lastname}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="${studentId.email}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="update" class="save"  /></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div align="right">
        <p>
            <a href="StudentControlllerServlet" >Back to List </a>
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Could you please be more precise on "update button does not work"? Errors, exceptions, ...?

Comment: Try to debug this. Add a breackpoint in servlet at first line in method and walk step by step to check the differences between first and second update.